# Adhoc performance view( Count of actual request to MS SQL server 2008 )

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I get adhoc performance view of MS SQL Server by using Select statement.
I need information, for example how many request and sessions are executing right now on database server.

Thanks 
Maharisi

Answer (score 0):

Query [sys.sysprocesses](http://sys.sysprocesses) (yes, it's deprecated but it's still damn useful and there is **no** direct replacement yet)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS NumConnex,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'sleeping' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NumActiveConnex
FROM
    sysprocesses
WHERE
    spid > 50 --exclude system SPIDs
```

Comment: Thanks, is it same possible for get count actual request or performance workload?

Comment: No idea what you mean now. This tells you active and connected. Do you mean your question was wrong and you meant to ask something else?